# What is Param[] and Params[] in Spark ML

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

As a statistic person, the logic of `Param` and `Params` class in Spark ML library confuses me a lot. Since the foundation class `PipelineStage extends Params`， and `transformer/estimator`( which means machine learning algorithms to me) are child class of `PipelineStage`. So `Params` is not just a simple class represented some machine learning parameters? And the access to some params in pipeline require certain parent requirement. I'm just so lost about how this come out...

Any logical explanation for Param? Thanks a lot! This really confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by these two concepts too. Below are my understanding of these two:

`Param` is in the package `scala.annotation.meta` that extends `Annotation`

`Params` is in the package `org.apache.spark.ml.param`, which is

> Trait for components that take parameters. This also provides an
>   internal param map to store parameter values attached to the instance.

Although `Params` is an interface, with the DeveloperApi, you can initiate one with

```
/**
 * :: DeveloperApi ::
 * A param with self-contained documentation and optionally default value. Primitive-typed param
 * should use the specialized versions, which are more friendly to Java users.
 *
 * @param parent parent object
 * @param name param name
 * @param doc documentation
 * @param isValid optional validation method which indicates if a value is valid.
 *                See [[ParamValidators]] for factory methods for common validation functions.
 * @tparam T param value type
 */
    class Param[T](val parent: String, val name: String, val doc: String, val isValid: T => Boolean)
      extends Serializable
```